# LSTM batch size and time series forecast window

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I am using a Long-short term memory (LSTM) deep network to forecast timeseries data.
One parameter of LSTMs is the so called "batch size". As I understand this determines the number of samples for one training/testing epoch (say we have a total of 1000 training and 100 test samples, then a batch size of 10 would, according to my understanding, mean that we have 10x a training/testing on 100/10 samples).

**My question**: As the batch-size determines the number of samples to train/test the LSTM on, is this equivalent to the forecasting *window*, i.e. how many steps in the past we take into account to make future predictions? Or, has the width of the window to be within the range of the size of the batch?

Comment: no, the batch size and window is different.

Comment: how so? if the batch size is the number of samples trained on, is then the width of the window << batch size?

Comment: typically the input will be a 3d array with shape [batch size, sequence (window) length, #features]